# How to run WCF service as x64

Tags: wcf, service, 64-bit

I have created an WCF Service that uses much memory. So I should run this service as an x64 process. But when I set platform=x64 and start debug I catch exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

How I can do it correctly? 
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

My service uses only one reference: *.NET -> System.ServiceModel*

Comment: Check your references. It sounds like you are referencing a 32-bit component.

Comment: How are you hosting the service? WcfServiceHost, a self-hosting EXE, or via ASP.NET?

Comment: Bizarre. I assume that if you're running on a 64-bit OS then you must be running 64-bit IIS as well, so that can't be the problem. I'm not sure what could be causing that error.

Comment: Try checking the FusionLog property of the BadImageFormatException (which is what I assume is what you are getting). That may give you more information as to what assembly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It means that one of your dependent assemblies (referenced or a project from the same solution) is set to a different CPU architecture. Check that all referenced assemblies or projects are set to x64 or Any CPU.